# User theme switching with SASS - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

So I have an rails admin system that will allow a user to choose a theme, basically a set of SASS color variables that will recompile application.css.scss with the new colors. How would be the best way of going about changing this when the user selects from a drop down and submits? I read some up on some problems with caching and recompiling but I'm not totally clear how to set it up.

Currently I have..

application.css.scss

```
@import "themes/whatever_theme";
@import "common";
@import "reset";
@import "base";
```

themes/_whatever_theme

```
$theme_sprite_path: '/images/sprite_theme_name.png';
$main_color:#009DDD;
$secondary_color:#b3d929;
$light_background:#f2f2f2;
$border_line:#e6e6e6;
$off_white:#f9f9f9;
$white:#ffffff;
$font_body:#565b59;
$font_headers:#363a36;
```

Say I have 5 different themes the user will switch between, it would be nice to set variable names for each theme in Rails then pass these down to SASS and change them on the fly and recompile. Is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: By the way, if you didn't know it, you are expected to accept an answer if you find it helpful (if there are several, pick the best one). This way you thank your peers for the help :-)

Comment: I missed that, sorted now. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

3 easy steps:

1. Compile all themes into different files upon deploy. This will take care of timestamping, zipping, etc.
2. Render page with default theme.
3. Use javascript to load alternate theme CSS.

No need to mess with dynamic compilation and all that.

To load a CSS dynamically you can use something like this:

```
function loadCSS(url) {
  var cssfile = document.createElement("link");
  cssfile.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  cssfile.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  cssfile.setAttribute("href", url);
}
```

Comment: Thinking about it this seems the easiest way to implement it. 

Essentially I could have..

`theme_one.css.scss
theme_two.css.scss`

Inside that include what I need...

`@import "themes/theme_one_colors";
@import "common";
@import "reset";
@import "base";'`

Then just call

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{theme_name}" %>`

and change when needed

I'm just trying to over complicate it I think :)

Comment: Depending on the amount of overlap between your themes, my suggestion might be more DRY

Answer (score 8):

Sergio's answer is valid, but omits the sassy details and I'd used a slightly different approach.

You're using SASS in Rails- don't fight the current, be Railsy and let the asset pipeline precompile all your CSS.  Unless you're trying to do something extreme like [CSSZenGarden](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/213/213.css&page=0) with **hundreds of themes**, or each theme is **thousands of lines** I'd recommend setting each theme as it's own CSS class rather than it's own file.

- 1kb of extra CSS in the rendered application.css file won't bog down your users
- It's straightforward to switch theme classes with JQuery: `$(".ThemedElement").removeClass([all your themes]).addClass("MyLittlePonyTheme");`
- As implied, you will have to tag the elements you want the update with the `ThemedElement` class

You could alternatively just change the class on your top level element and make liberal use of inheritance and the `!important` declaration, although I find the other approach more maintainable.

If you think you can manage your themes with classes rather than files, here's how we generate them with SASS.  SASS doesn't support json style objects, so we have to reach way back and set up a bunch of parallel arrays with the theme properties.  Then we iterate over each theme, substitute the dynamic properties into the auto generated theme class, and you're off to the races:

**themes.css.scss**

```
@import "global.css.scss";

/* iterate over each theme and create a CSS class with the theme's properties */
@for $i from 1 through 4{

            /* here are the names and dynamic properties for each theme class */
    $name: nth(("DefaultTheme", 
                        "MyLittlePonyTheme",
                        "BaconTheme",
                        "MySpaceTheme"
                        ), $i);
    $image: nth(("/assets/themes/bg_1.png", 
                         "/assets/themes/bg_2.png",
                         "/assets/themes/bg_3.png",
                         "/assets/themes/bg_4.png"
                        ), $i);
    $primary: nth((#7ca8cb,
                           #3c6911,
                           #d25d3a,
                           #c20d2c
                          ), $i);
    $font: nth((Rosario, 
                        Helvetica,
                        Comic Sans,
                        WingDings
                       ), $i);


    /* Now we write our Theme CSS and substitute our properties when desired */
.#{$name}{
    &.Picker{
      background-image:url($image);
    }
    color: $primary;
    .BigInput, h1{
      color: $primary;
      font-family: $font, sans-serif !important;
    }
    .Frame{
        background-image:url($image);
    }
    .Blank:hover{
        background-color:mix('#FFF', $primary, 90%) !important;
    }
    .BigButton{
        background-color:$primary;
        @include box-shadow(0,0,10px, $primary);
    }
            /* and so on... */
       }
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it's served us really well.  If your themes are uber complicated or you have too many of them it gets more painful to maintain.

Comment: Great answer! I liked this idea a lot. Also, points for recognizing pitfalls in your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to simply load a set of custom css rules (your theme) after your application.css and let your theme override the default colors from application.css. You could just add a database column "theme" and load the css with this name dynamically like.

SASS is not designed for compiling dynamic data on the fly. If you want dynamic css processing, you could add a controller method called "custom_css" and make this respond to the css format and load this dynamically with inline variables, but I don't think SASS is meant to be used for it at all.

Comment: Yes, Sergio's suggestions are great. I'd always split theme.css and application.css, just seems more clean to me.

Comment: Database is a good suggestion too, although this only makes sense to me if you need to support user-defined themes.  Otherwise you're storing / migrating / managing presentation details in the application's data layer.  This seems like a poor workflow and performance choice.

Comment: Oh I understood this as if the user must choose his theme which should be stored and used for his profile. In this case I wouldn't know of any other way than storing the theme name in the database.

Comment: Yep the user would choose a theme which would then be stored in the db, I have gone down Segio's suggested rout for now but thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could use erb to inline variables in sass.  I'm not positive, but I think it would look something like this:

themes/_whatever_theme.sass.erb

```
$theme_sprite_path: '<%= Theme.sprite_path %>';
$main_color: <%= Theme.main_color %>;
$secondary_color: <%= Theme.secondary_color %>;
```

These should be created dynamically for each page load.  I'm not sure how the caching would work here.

Comment: That basically defeats the whole purpose of Asset Pipeline :-)

Comment: It could just as easily be done in a assets/stylesheets/style.sass.erb file.