# Set Sass variable from controller action in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I made a file called template.css.scss in my Rails app that holds all the color styling that I want dynamically changed based on a user's preferences.

Here's a little sample of it:

```
/* pink */
$lighter-shade: #F75F9E;
$darker-shade: #B54573;

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: $lighter-shade;
}

#command-header {
  color: $darker-shade;
}
```

I thought I could do a migration to add a column to track the user's styling preference. Of course, there would be a default setting. Then I could update the Sass variables based on the preference.

Unfortunately, from my research it seems like the way to go is to create separate templates and then set those dynamically based on the user's preference. I really hope that's not the case because the way I have things structured right now is concise and efficient, and I'd hate to lose that.

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to handle: get the user's preference and put it into a

```
data-user-preference="<%= current_user.pref %>">
```

then use jquery to add the appropriate class based on that pref

```
$('.class-name').data('user-preference').addClass('whatever')
```

Comment: True but that's a lot of overhead. I'd rather do the setting on the back-end.

Comment: setting will happen on backend no matter what. hacky way to do it if you're trying not to use js and don't want to render partials: 

```ruby

<% if current_user.pref == 'Choice A' %>
   <div class="my-class">
<% elsif _____

etc.

```

Comment: Ohhh. I see what you're saying now!

Comment: I still think the answer I posted is superior way to this but either will work :)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744941/user-theme-switching-with-sass-ruby-on-rails?rq=1
Just found it.

Comment: still not as easy as mine. heavier than you need. but whatever you like.

Comment: I'm adding data-user-preference to my css file to avoid setting jQuery. ex: [data-user-preference="black"] {
  color: black;
}